# setSelectedItem method is not working

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am having problems with the setSelectedItem method of JComboBox. It is just not working.Here is my code; My Station and Division classes are ok. So they are not included.
No matter what I try I am not able to set an item as selected in the ComboBox;

```
//ListItem Class

public class ListItem {
private String id;
private String value;

public ListItem()
{

    id = "";
    value = "";
}
public ListItem(String id, String value)
{

    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;

}

public String getID(){return this.id;}
public String getValue() { return this.value;}

public void setID(String id ){this.id = id;}
public void setValue(String value) {this.value = value;}
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return value;
}


//show station
private void showSelectedStation(String stationCode){


    stationDA = new StationDA();
    station = stationDA.getStationByCode(stationCode);

    //Assign values to Division fields
    jtxtStationCode.setText(Integer.toString(station.getStationCode()));
    jtxtStationName.setText(station.getStationName());


    divisionDA = new DivisionDA();
    division = divisionDA.getDivisionByCode(station.getDivisionCode());



    ListItem myItem = new ListItem(
    division.getDivisionCode(), division.getDivisionName());


    jcbDivisionName.setSelectedItem(myItem); //not working.Only the first Value in the     list is showing


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListItem myItem = new ListItem(
division.getDivisionCode(), division.getDivisionName());
jcbDivisionName.setSelectedItem(myItem);
```

You are using a custom Object. You need to implement the equals() method in order for the comboBox to select the correct item.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I don't believe i understand you. How will I implement the equals method in this context?

Comment: @user2483307, See [Combo Box With Hidden Data](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/). The Item class shows how this might be done. In fact you can probably even use this class since it was designed to do what you are doing (from what I can tell of your code).

Answer (score 1):

ListItem must implement the `equals` method so `JComboBox` can match the item.

Something like:

```
public class ListItem {
    //your code

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) 
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof ListItem)) 
            return false;

        ListItem other= (ListItem) obj;
        if (this.name.equals(other.name)) 
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Assuming that you have the name field. Just compare whatever you want to compare.